# Docker - can not connect to remote DB

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker for windows. I have some containers (dev-httpd, dev-mysql etc.) I'm trying to download database from the remote (make copy of it in my dev-mysql container) and I **cannot connect to that database from docker**. When I run some database tool (for example Adminer) via xampp and insert the values from SQL command with login and password **I can connect into it** (I can see the databases, see data, ...).

Do I need somehow set the firewall rule in the virtual docker machine to allow remote database?

I'm starting docker on window starts, then I use the **docker-compose up -d** (that starts all containers I need) and then I login via **docker exec -ti dev-httpd bash** command.

Does anyone know what could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with localhost and 0.0.0.0

Localhost allow you to access the port only from that machine, using 0.0.0.0 will let it be visible outside. Or just use your IP instead of default.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your database is not available with a public IP address or public host name. From inside your container, you can access only public IP addresses or hostnames because, by default, your container won't be aware of your local network configuration.

I think you'd be more successful using **host networking** with the `--network host` option of docker run. See (https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)